# Wrong int values using fwrite in C

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread

I'm trying to create a keymanager for a simple UDP client-server application in C. I'm running into problems writing the keys to a text file. I'm currently storing structs into a txt file, but my output was the same when I used ints.

```
// ...
// if the principal is requesting to registering, store it in a file
if (req.request_type == regista) {
    printf("Writing key to file...\n");
    pFile = fopen("crypt.txt", "ab");
    fwrite(&req, sizeof(struct P2Key), 1, pFile);
    printf("Written: %u %i ", req.principal_id, req.public_key);
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("Done\n");
}

// if pincipal is requesting key
if (req.request_type == request_key) {
    pFile = fopen("crypt.txt", "rb");
    printf("Key requested for: %u %i ", req.principal_id, req.public_key);
    printf("Searching for Requested Key\n");

    while (fread(&res, sizeof(struct P2Key), 1, pFile) == 1) {
        printf("Read: %u %i\n", res.principal_id, res.public_key);
        printf("Line Number: %ld\n", ftell(pFile));

        // if this is the client requested, send the key
        if (req.principal_id == res.principal_id) {
            send_key.principal_id = req.principal_id;
            send_key.public_key = req.public_key;
            printf("Sending Key...\n");
            // ...
        }
```

Here's the structure being written to the file

```
typedef struct P2Key {
    enum {
        regista, request_key
    } request_type; /* same size as an unsigned int */
    unsigned int principal_id; /* client or server identifier */
    int public_key; /*  public key */
} P2Key;
```

The output I'm getting when I attempt to read the file:

```
 Writing key to file...
 Written: 2 7 Done
 ...
 Writing key to file...
 Written: 1 7 Done
 Key requested for: 2 7 Searching for Requested Key
 Read: 512 1792
 Line Number: 12
 Read: 256 1792
 Line Number: 24
 End of file reached.
```

I've been at this for hours, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit odd to have a file extension of `.txt` (typically meaning humanly readable "text"), but creating the file as binary (which is what the `b` in your `ab` option means). So it's a little unclear what you're really expecting here. Have you tried doing a hex dump of your file to see what it looks like?

Comment: find out if the the write or the read thats broken. Write the file and inspect it with 'od'. Does the file look good? BTW I would have written a text file not raw binary

Comment: You are opening the file for writing with `"ab"`, which is _append_ mode. So, if you've been debugging a while, you may not have things aligned. I'd restart the test with an empty `crypt.txt` file to be absolutely sure (e.g. delete the file first).

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, then post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: OT: when calling any C library function, always check for any error.  With `fopen()` check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful,  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" ); to send both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing in append mode; have you re-created the file since you switched to writing the structs?  You don't show or even test the number of bytes written, so you have no idea if the write succeeded or not.

My first suspect is that you have been appending to this file over time, and it has old data near the beginning that doesn't line up with your structure.  I suggest first emptying the file.  On UNIX/Linux, you can do this with "> crypt.txt" from the shell.

Now on to debugging the code.  Capture the return value of all reads and writes, they return size_t, so you can at least look at the return value in the debugger.  You may want to log an error, etc., if you didn't write the number of bytes you expected to -- the sizeof the struct.  Step over the write and close in your debugger, then look at the file with a hex dump or similar utility.  Do the values in the file look like what you expect?  Does the file contain the same number of bytes as the sizeof your struct?

Then proceed to the read code.  Watch the code load each value from the file with fread.  Watch the return value you get from fread -- is it the sizeof your struct?  Look at the values in the struct after the read completes.  Does it look like it read what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

Your program appears to work here. Note that I'm using linux, but since you're using `b` in your `fopen` args, even if you are using WinX, it should still be the same.

I had to synthesize some missing elements to get a full program. I passed down `req` from `main`, so the [new] `action` function had to use `req->*` instead of `req.*`, but, otherwise it should be the same as your code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct P2Key {
    enum {
        regista, request_key
    } request_type;                     /* same size as an unsigned int */
    unsigned int principal_id;          /* client or server identifier */
    int public_key;                     /* public key */
} P2Key;

void
action(P2Key *req)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    P2Key res;
    P2Key send_key;

    printf("request_type=%d regista=%d request_key=%d\n",
        req->request_type,regista,request_key);

// ...
// if the principal is requesting to registering, store it in a file
    if (req->request_type == regista) {
        printf("Writing key to file...\n");
        pFile = fopen("crypt.txt", "ab");
        fwrite(req, sizeof(struct P2Key), 1, pFile);
        printf("Written: %u %i ", req->principal_id, req->public_key);
        fclose(pFile);
        printf("Done\n");
    }

// if pincipal is requesting key
    if (req->request_type == request_key) {
        pFile = fopen("crypt.txt", "rb");
        printf("Key requested for: %u %i ", req->principal_id, req->public_key);
        printf("Searching for Requested Key\n");

        while (fread(&res, sizeof(struct P2Key), 1, pFile) == 1) {
            printf("Read: %u %i\n", res.principal_id, res.public_key);
            printf("Line Number: %ld\n", ftell(pFile));

            // if this is the client requested, send the key
            if (req->principal_id == res.principal_id) {
                send_key.principal_id = req->principal_id;
                send_key.public_key = req->public_key;
                printf("Sending Key...\n");
                // ...
            }
        }

        fclose(pFile);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    P2Key req;

    while (1) {
        printf("Cmd (regista=%d request_key=%d): ",regista,request_key);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&req.request_type);
        scanf("%u %d",&req.principal_id,&req.public_key);

        action(&req);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the output I got:

```
Cmd (regista=0 request_key=1): 0 5 6
request_type=0 regista=0 request_key=1
Writing key to file...
Written: 5 6 Done
Cmd (regista=0 request_key=1): 0 8 9
request_type=0 regista=0 request_key=1
Writing key to file...
Written: 8 9 Done
Cmd (regista=0 request_key=1): 1 8 9
request_type=1 regista=0 request_key=1
Key requested for: 8 9 Searching for Requested Key
Read: 1 2
Line Number: 12
Read: 5 6
Line Number: 24
Read: 8 9
Line Number: 36
Sending Key...
Cmd (regista=0 request_key=1): ^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your file, it appears that there may be an extra byte (or bytes) in there for some reason, which is causing you to read the structures at an incorrect offset.

I base this on the following:

1. You simply append a structure to the existing file, regardless of how many bytes are currently in the file; and
2. The values you're reading are exact multiples of `256`. More importantly, they are `256` multiplied by `1`, `2` and `7` (`256`, `512` and `1792`).

An easy way to check is to simply delete the file (or empty it) and run your program again. Provided you don't have anything else writing to the file, it should work okay.

---

There are actually ways you can catch this sort of issue, should you be so inclined. They include, amongst others:

- checking that the file size is an exact multiple of the structure size when opening.
- adding an indicator field (or fields) to your structure for checking each and every item, such as a field at the start called `check_dead` and another at the end called `check_beef`, which you *always* set to `0xdead` and `0xbeef` on writing a record and *always* check when reading one.